# How to use a variable inside itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fullcalendar-4

I want to use the variable inside itself and I see other people do it but why does it not work for me?

This is my ES6 file

```
// Setup module
// ------------------------------

var FullCalendarAdmin = function () {

    //
    // Setup module components
    //
    var _componentRender = function () {

    // Basic calendar
    var _componentFullCalendarAdmin = function (events) {

        // Define element
        var calendarAgendaViewElement = document.querySelector('.fullcalendar-agenda-admin');

        // Initialize
        if (calendarAgendaViewElement) {
            var calendarAgendaViewInit = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarAgendaViewElement, {
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'interaction'],
                select: function (start, end) {
                    var title = prompt("Add event:");
                    var data;
                    if (title != '') {
                        data = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        };
                        calendarAgendaViewInit.addEvent(data);
                    }
            }).render();

        }
    };

    //
    // Return objects assigned to module
    //

    return {
        init: function () {
            _componentRender();
        }
    }
}();


// Initialize module
// ------------------------------

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    FullCalendarAdmin.init();
});
```

How can I use the `calendarAgendaViewInit` to call the `addEvent` function without getting function as an undefined error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're declaring "functions for itself" _inside a function_, what you're trying to write is an object class: [write one of those instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: Thanks! looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you invoke `.render` immediately.
So your `calendarAgendaViewInit` is not an instance of `FullCalendar.Calendar` but the result of the `render` method.
What you can do is first define the `calendarAgendaViewInit` variable

```js
var calendarAgendaViewInit = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarAgendaViewElement, {
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'interaction'],
                select: function (start, end) {
                    var title = prompt("Add event:");
                    var data;
                    if (title != '') {
                        data = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        };
                        calendarAgendaViewInit.addEvent(data);
                    }
            });
```

and then call `calendarAgendaViewInit.render()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of an expanded explanation to the comment above. It looks like `calendarAgendaViewElement` is simply a DOM element that you've found and assigned to a variable. The problem here is that you can only call methods on class instantiations that are now objects with methods inside. If you had seen others call `addEvent` like that, then they were likely calling it on an instantiation of a class meaning that `addEvent` had been previously declared as part of that class and they are simply calling that method.

See the example below,

If I declare a class as follows:

```
class Sample {
   sayHello(){
      console.log('hello')
    }
 }
```

Then instantiate a new object of the 'Sample' class:

```
var sampleClass = new Sample()
```

Then I can call 'sayHello' by referring to the method inside the object

`sampleClass.sayHello() // hello`

Hope that helps